# What does the formal definition of "closed-form" say about finite sums exactly?

Tags: summation, closed-form

I have looked through the online literature and there seems to be conflicting answers to this question. Consider the finite sum

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} {n-1\choose i}$$

Is this expression considered closed-form?

These two links say that such a finite sum is not considered closed-form:

1. [https://opendsa-server.cs.vt.edu/ODSA/Books/CS3/html/Summations.html#:~:text=This%20is%20known%20as%20a%20closed%2Dform%20solution](https://opendsa-server.cs.vt.edu/ODSA/Books/CS3/html/Summations.html#:%7E:text=This%20is%20known%20as%20a%20closed%2Dform%20solution)
2. http://www3.govst.edu/wrudloff/CPSC438/CPSC438/CH05/Chapter5/Section.5.2.pdf

while this link says that such a finite sum *is* considered closed-form:

3. [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression#:~:text=Yes-,Finite%20sum,Yes,-Finite%20product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression#:%7E:text=Yes-,Finite%20sum,Yes,-Finite%20product)

As far as I know, a closed-form expression has a finite number of standard operations or known functions. Based on this, my hunch is that the sum above is closed-form.

Comment: Since you cannot bound the number of terms in that sum when considered over all $n$, some people might argue it is too general to be a finite sum.

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70848/what-does-a-closed-form-solution-mean

Comment: @Henry that's an interesting point. is it formally accepted that if you cannot bound the number of terms in an expression, then it isn't closed-form? you say "some people might argue" so it seems like the question of whether or not the above sum is closed-form can't really be answered definitively

Comment: You ask what is *the formal definition* of closed-form.  Why does there have to be a single definition rather than what a particular user defines it to be?

Comment: @Henry It's not that there _needs_ to be a single definition, but math is largely built on unambiguous definitions which gives it its black-and-white characteristic. If such a universal definition exists in the math literature, I would like to follow it. If there truly isn't such a formal definition, then I can live with the ambiguity, but I first need to know that there isn't a universally accepted definition of closed-form. So I guess my question really is, is there a clear-cut definitive answer to the question I have posed above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** The notion of *closed form* in mathematics is context dependent. Finite sums of type
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} {n-1\choose i}
\end{align*}
are usually *not* considered to be in closed form, since there is bound index variable $i$.

> We find in Chapter I: *What Is Enumerative Combinatorics?* in the classic *[Enumerative Combinatorics, Vol. I](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/enumerative-combinatorics-vol-i)* by R. P. Stanley:
>
> The basic problem of enumerative combinatorics is that of counting the number of elements of a finite set. Usually we are given an infinite collection of finite sets $S_i$ where $i$ ranges over some index set $I$ (such as the nonnegative integers $\mathbb{N}$), and we wish to count the number $f(i)$ of elements in each $S_i$ *simultaneously*. Immediate philosophical difficulties arise. What does it mean to *count* the number of elements of $S_i$? There is no definite answer to this question. Only through experience does one develop an idea of what is meant by a *determination* of a counting function $f(i)$. The counting function $f(i)$ can be given in several standard ways:
>
> - The most satisfactory form of $f(i)$ is a complete explicit closed formula involving only well-known functions, and free from summation symbols.

*Note:* The crucial aspect is the term *[bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables#Examples)* variable. As long as there are bound variables with limited scope given by $\Sigma$ or $\prod$ symbols, the expression is not considered to be in *closed form*.

Comment: This answer was helpful, thank you! I think the most convincing way for me to see that it isn't closed-form is to notice that the number of terms grows to infinity as n goes to infinity, whereas in a truly closed-form algebraic expression, n may grow to infinity but the number of terms is more or less constant, i.e. the set of terms is always finite.

Comment: @SNN: You're welcome. I've also added a note which might be helpful.