# Is factorial considered a closed formula?

Tags: soft-question, terminology, closed-form

I know this is a tricky question, but I'm curious if factorial is truly considered a closed formula? We all know that:

$$
\prod_{i=1}^n i = n!
$$

I've always considered the LHS to not be a closed formula and the RHS to be a closed formula. But from another viewpoint, is the exclamation point just a notation for the LHS? If this is the case, can we truly consider the RHS to be a closed formula? Moreover, it's just shorthand.

The same goes for a summation. In my head, I've always believed a closed formula did not include any iteration or recursion, even if it's finite. An example of iteration is Gauss' sum of consecutive integers from $1$ to $n$:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n \left( n + 1 \right)}{2}
$$

Again, the LHS is not a closed formula, but the RHS is. An example of recursion is the Fibonacci sequence:

$$
F_n = F_{n-1} + F_{n-2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \left( \varphi^n - \phi^n \right)
$$

The middle is not a closed formula, but the RHS is. I know there are tons of examples, but these are just a few simple examples off the top of my head.

So, is factorial really a closed formula? If someone derived a formula that included a factorial, can we consider that to be a closed formula? In fact, are binomial coefficients closed formulas, since:

$$
\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k! \left( n - k \right)!}
$$

Any insight to this will greatly be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: "Closed formula" is not a well-defined notion. It's as simple as that.

Comment: Maybe it's a matter of opinion, but I'd have no problem calling a formula with factorials a closed form.

Comment: What one calls a closed formula depends on the context. If I'm solving an integral with a parameter and reduce it to a finite sum dependent on that parameter, I might call that a closed formula. However, there would be some cases where I wouldn't call that a closed formula, for example, if the sum reduced to a simpler form.

Comment: For what it's worth,$$\binom nk=\left\lfloor\frac{(u+1)^n}{u^k}\right\rfloor\operatorname{mod}u$$for $u>2^n$. (Note that $a\operatorname{mod}b$ can be defined as $a-b\lfloor a/b\rfloor$.) Finally,$$n!=\left\lfloor\frac{r^n}{\binom rn}\right\rfloor$$for $r>(2x)^{x+1}$.

Comment: Therefore if you consider $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ to be "closed-form" (which, as explained by others, does not have a precise technical definition), then we can give a (complicated) closed-form expression for the factorial.

Comment: (I'm realizing, I'm not actually certain what class of functions from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N$ can be represented as a combination of $+$, $-$, $\times$, $\div$, exponentiation, and $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$. It's probably a large class…)

Comment: Based on your examples, an expression is not in closed form if it has a free index. If we suppose the inverse is also true,  this might actually be a pretty good starting point for a definition. For integrals, $dx$ could be considered to be the index.

Comment: If you consider that $n!$ is not a closed formula, I suppose that you consider $a^n$ is not a closed formula. For both formulas, it is necessary to 'loop' many steps to calculate this.

Comment: It's denotation is *highly* context dependent - similar to that of "number". But - contrary to an above claim - it is well-defined in certain contexts. This is true even for more well established terms, e.g. algebraic structures like "rings" and "domains" (though there is much less variation, e.g. varying on whether they have $1$ and hom's preserve $1$ or whether they are commutative, associative, etc). It often proves convenient to locally modify definitions as need be, and this is often done in mathematics (esp. if there is no (nearly) standard denotation).

Answer (score 2):

A helpful discussion of this aspect is given in in section 1.2 in *[Concrete Mathematics](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Er97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf)* by R.L. Graham, D. Knuth and O. Patashnik. We need some formulas which are cited in the text below.
\begin{align*}
T_0&=0\\
T_n&=2T_{n-1}+1\qquad\qquad\quad\ \ \text{for}\  n>0\tag{1.1}\\
\\
T_n&=2^{n}-1\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\text{for}\  n\geq 0\tag{1.2}\\
\\
L_0&=1\\
L_n&=L_{n-1}+n\qquad\qquad\qquad\text{for}\  n>0\tag{1.4}\\
\\
L_n&=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+1\qquad\qquad\;\text{for}\  n\geq 0\tag{1.6}\\
\end{align*}

> The following is verbatim from section 1.2:
>
> - Incidentally we've been talking about *closed forms* without explicitly saying what we mean. Usually it's pretty clear. Recurrences like (1.1) and (1.4) are not in closed form - they express a quantity in terms of itself; but solutions like (1.2) and (1.6) are. Sums like $1+2+\cdots+n$ are not in closed form - they cheat by using ' $\cdots$'; but expressions like $n(n+1)/2$ are.
> - We could give a rough definition like this: An expression for a quantity $f(n)$ is in *closed form* if we can compute it using at most a  fixed number of *well known* standard operations, independent of $n$. For example, $2n-1$ and $n(n+1)/2$ are closed forms because they involve only addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, and exponentiation, in explicit ways. The total number of simple closed forms is limited, and there are recurrences that don't have simple closed forms. When such recurrences turn out to be important, because they arise repeatedly, we add new operations to our repertoire; this can greatly extend the range of problems solvable in *simple* closed form.
> - For example, the product of the first $n$  integers, $n!$, has proved to be so important that we now consider it a basic operation. The formula $n!$ is therefore in closed form, although its equivalent $1\cdot 2\cdots n$ is not.

We conclude from these explanations: The right-hand side of the identity
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\prod_{i=1}^ni=n!}
\end{align*}
is given in *closed form* whereas the left-hand side is not in closed form. Whenever we have *[bound variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables)* as the index $i$ in the product above, we don't have a closed form representation.

> Richard P. Stanley indicates this in *[Enumerative Combinatocis](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/enumerative-combinatorics-vol-i)* section 1.1 when he tells us:
>
> - The most satisfactory form of $f(i)$ is a complete explicit closed formula involving only well-known functions, and free from summation symbols.

For more information on this extract, see *[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4421120/what-does-the-formal-definition-of-closed-form-say-about-finite-sums-exactly/4421838#4421838)*.

Comment: Funny how you mention the former book. I actually bought that book a few weeks ago, but I have yet to read it, except for a few pages in chapter 3.

Comment: @RJOnyxMoonshadow: I appreciate this book very much. Enjoy reading it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the subject and the person, whether the factorial is considered closed-form or not would differ. For example, in combinatorics, the factorial is used so regularly that it is basically considered closed form since the factorial is a standard operation. However, in subjects like real analysis, the factorial is used sparingly enough to not be considered as a standard operation, and it would not be treated as closed form. It is however used in Taylor series expansions, so it is useful even in real analysis.

Also, the notion of closed-form-ness is not very useful now, since it is meant for ease of approximation and computers can approximate basically anything. In [this video,](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZdQFN2XKeKI) at 14:08, James Grime claims that the approximation was "easier to work out," and at 14:29 "if you wanted to work it out, you'd be better off approximating." Even though that particular case uses very complicated formulas, this might be true in other cases as well.

Comment: Why is $\sum$ not closed form but $\int$ is? I feel integrals are even _less_ 'closed-form'…

Comment: I believe it to be totally subjective.

Comment: Also, as far as I'm aware, the factorial is pretty universally considered a standard operation across mathematics, including real analysis, not just in discrete areas like combinatorics.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger What a closed form is depends on the aim. Finite $\sum$ can be defined as closed forms, but infinite sums are usually not defined as closed forms. If the elementary functions are defined as the only closed forms, $\int$ and factorials aren't closed forms.