# What does it mean when the stopping point is equal to the index in a summation?

Tags: summation, combinations, binomial-coefficients

$$\sum_{k=0}^{k=n}k\ \binom{n}{k}$$
Find a closed formula for the sum. The index is $k=0$ and the stopping point is $k=0$ so I am assuming the process is that the combination iterates from $^nC_k$ to $^nC_n$. How would i show that in a closed formula? I am confused on what a closed formula is in the first place. What I am assuming is that it is a formula that represents the summation and gives the same values when substituting in the values. However i am not sure how to go about it.

Comment: If the problem were "Find a closed formula for the sum $\sum_{k = 0}^{k=n}\binom nk$", the expected answer would be $2^n$, as the two expressions yield the same value whatever $n$ is, and it is so-called "closed form", which is a semi-rigorous way of saying "simplified". In your problem the answer will be a bit bigger, and presumably not _quite_ that simple, but that's the kind of answer they are after.

Comment: The index is not $k=0.$ The index is $k$ and its **starting point** is $0.$ Therefore the combination $\binom nk$ iterates from $\binom n0$, next to $\binom n1,$ next to $\binom n2,$ and so forth up to and including $\binom nn$. A "closed formula" implies that only certain well-known functions are used and only a fixed number of terms are involved in the formula. Anything that starts with $\sum_{k=0}^{k=n}$, where $n$ is a variable, cannot be a closed form because the number of terms will depend on $n$ and is not a fixed number of terms.

Comment: Note that if you write the sum using $+\cdots+$ notation, you get $0\binom n0 + 1\binom n1 + 2\binom n2 + 3\binom n3 + \cdots + n\binom nn.$ No variable $k$ is required here; the job of $k$ was to help us see the rule for generating each of the terms in that sum, and once we use it for that purpose we don't need it any more.

Answer (score 1):

By definition of $\sum$ you have that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n f(k)=f(0)+f(1)+\ldots +f(n)
$$
It doesn't matter if $n$ is in the definition of $f$, as $n$ is a constant. Now, for the solution, observe that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n k \binom{n}{k}=\left[\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} kx^k\right]_{x=1}
=\left[\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} x\frac{d}{d x}x^k\right]_{x=1}=\left[x\frac{d}{d x}\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} x^k\right]_{x=1}=\ldots 
$$
I hope you can follow from here.

Comment: where did $kx^{k}$ come from, is there a formal defintion for closed form? and what was the point of redefining the summation with f(x)

Comment: @iimonchii Your problem is a pretty typical combinatorics problem and I assume an introductory textbook would have you string together a few identities to reach an answer.  Masacroso here is instead using some techniques for manipulating "Generating Functions" to work toward the answer.

Answer (score 1):

A closed formula here means a representation without a sum symbol (and without using a *[bound variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables)* as index variable $k$).

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^nk\binom{n}{k}}&=\sum_{k=1}^nk\binom{n}{k}\tag{1}\\
> &=n\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n-1}{k-1}\tag{2}\\
> &=n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k}\tag{3}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=n2^{n-1}}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}
> where $n2^{n-1}$ is a *closed form* representation.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we start with the index $k=1$ since the summand with $k=0$ does not contribute.
- In (2) we use the binomial identity $\binom{p}{q}=\frac{p}{q}\binom{p-1}{q-1}$.
- In (3) we shift the index to start with $k=0$.
- In (4) we apply the binomial theorem.

**Hint:** Some more information about a *closed formula* is given in *[this MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4421120)*.

Comment: Thank you i understand alot more, could you please explain comment 2 more as I've never seen or at least recognized that identity. does p/q = n?

Comment: @iimonchii: You're welcome. We have $\binom{p}{q}=\frac{p!}{q!(p-q)!}=\frac{p\cdot (p-1)!}{q\cdot (q-1)!(p-q)!}=\frac{p}{q}\binom{p-1}{q-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

> What does it mean when the stopping point is equal to the index in a summation?... The index is k=0 and the stopping point is k=n...

I think you are a bit confused about the way that the sigma notation works.
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{k=n} k \binom{n}{k}
$$
In this example, $k$ is the index and it starts at $0$ and continues up until it reaches $n$, and each $k\binom{n}{k}$ term is evaluated for each allowed value of $k$.  In other words:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{k=n} k \binom{n}{k}=\Bigg[k \binom{n}{k}\Bigg]_{k=0}+\Bigg[k \binom{n}{k}\Bigg]_{k=1}+\Bigg[k \binom{n}{k}\Bigg]_{k=2} + \ ... + \Bigg[k \binom{n}{k}\Bigg]_{k=n}
$$
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{k=n} k \binom{n}{k}=\Bigg[0 \binom{n}{0}\Bigg]+\Bigg[1 \binom{n}{1}\Bigg]+\Bigg[2 \binom{n}{2}\Bigg] + \ ... + \Bigg[n \binom{n}{n}\Bigg]
$$
The part about finding a "closed formula" is just asking for you to simplify the expression into a form that no longer requires a summation.  This will require the use of multiple different identities and is covered by other users answers very well.